# Can we model this set of experiments as an stochastic process and estimate the sample size?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, sampling

I have an  image with the size `5575x9440` and I'm implementing [a modified version of the algorithm used in this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5659970&refinements%3D4225530238%26filter%3DAND%28p_IS_Number%3A5719225%29) on it, but because the code performance is low right now, I have divided the image to `52628` submatrices of the size `25x40 (1000 pixels)` and my first experiments show that some lines of code that are marked in the following picture as yellow are not needed at all (meaning that the 2 and 3 degree polynomials always have at least one real positive root) and so there's no need to check it. (Deleting these ten lines will make the code 3rd times faster and I have other plans to accelerate the code further)

[image]

Because the code is slow right now, I cannot experiment all of these `52628` matrices and I have to choose a sample size and choose some random matrices to try. **But how to calculate the sample size?**

What comes below is just to show my effort. And if you're not willing to read it, there's no necessity.

---

### I've already done as follows

---

This is for lines 121 and 122. The approach for the other two lines (134 and 135) is the same.

We want to test the following hypothesis.

**Hypothesis: the line 121, 122 will not be run even one time for the whole image.**

**Hypothesis(scientifically): We can be 95% or 99% (confidence level) sure that those lines will be run just for 0.25% pixels (confidence interval) of the image.**

Up to know I have tried this way:

First of all  we have a random variable **X = two lines of code** that can have just two values: **they will run (1)** or **they will not run(0)**. So the random variable  will have the [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution)

For each pixel, this experiment is done `62271` times and so in each submatrix, it will be done `62271000` times independently. So the random variable **X = Number of times that the 2 lines are run** that its value can be an integer number in the range $[0,62271000]$ is the sum of a huge number (`62271000`) of `bernoulli distributed variables` and so **X** will have a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) according to the [Central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) so the random variable **Z**:
$$Z=\frac{X-np}{\sqrt{npq}}$$

---

**Edit:** (Based on the discussion between me and @Wiley in the comments) I should say that from the theoretic concepts of my model, I know that $\Delta>0$ for 2d and 3d polynomials. So the roots are real but it is their sign that determines whether the highlighted cod is needed or not

**For 2D Polynomials:** there are 4 cases

[image]
if there's at least one positive root, the highlighted code is not needed ($p=\frac{3}{4}$)
if all of the roots are negative, the highlighted code is needed. ($q=\frac{1}{4}$)

**For 3D Polynomials:** there are 8 cases
[image]
if there's at least one positive root, the highlighted code is not needed ($p=\frac{7}{8}$)
if all of the roots are negative, the highlighted code is needed. ($q=\frac{1}{8}$)

---

will have a [Standard normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution)
So for the 3d polynomial we have: $p=\frac{7}{8}\;,q=\frac{1}{8}$ and also $n = 62271000$, so we will have:
$$Z = \frac{X-54487125}{5219}\qquad 0\le X\le 62271000\Rightarrow -10440\le Z\le 1491$$

***But from now on, I thinking I'm making some mistakes.***

---

Our confidence interval is `0.25% of pixels`
$$0.25\times 0.01\times 5575\times 9440 = 131570$$

meaning that the number of pixels that do not fit our hypothesis should be less than `131570`
If we assume that these pixels are distributed homogeneously across the whole image, then the number of pixels in each submatrix that do not fit our hypothesis should be less than:
$$\frac{131570}{52628}=2.5$$
so $0\le X\le 155677.5\Rightarrow -10440\le Z\le -10410$
so our confidence interval is $-10410-(-10440)=30$
and our confidence level is 95% or 99%, means that the probability that $Z$ lies in the above range should be `0.95` or `0.99`.
$$p(Z)=N(0,1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})$$
$$p(-10440\le Z\le -10410)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-10440}^{-10410}\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})\,dz = 0.95\; \text{or}\; 0.99$$
Then if we consider `52628` matrices as a stochastic process as a collection of `52628` (population) random variables with `standard normal distribution`, how many members of this process should be experimented (sample size)?

Comment: I might misunderstand the graphs you posted, but I'm not sure why you think that the probability p=1/2 in your Bernoulli model, given that the code highlighted only ran a few hundred of times out of ~62 million runs.  Your objective is to confirm that this probability is tiny so you could remove these lines that are computationally heavy, right?  I can see two ways of proceeding: (1) use the data you have collected from these sub-matrices to estimate this probability p and its confidence level, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval (cont.)

Comment: (2) if you know ab initio what the distribution of d's that go into your quadratic / cubic equations, there are ways to calculate the probability of these equations having a real positive root (based on random matrix theory).

Comment: @Wiley as you see in the tables of the graphs, we have: `Code lines that did not run: 2` and those lines are `root=0;end;`. Because the if statement is never true. (meaning that the 2d/3d polynomials always have at least 1 positive root). Now I say because the code is written for polynomials of $\Delta>0$, which have real roots, the are two possibilities. For a 3d polynomial 1- at least one of the roots is positive ($p=\frac{7}{8}$) **the code will not run**  2-all of the roots are negative ($q=\frac{1}{8}$) **the code will run**. And for a 2d polynomial 1- at least one of the roots is

Comment: @Wiley positive $(p=\frac{3}{4})$ **the code will not run** 2-all of the roots are negative $(q=\frac{1}{4})$ **the code will run**. Yes, you were right

Comment: @Wiley I'm going to take your first way. I have selected 30 of these matrices and I do run my code on those matrices to find that probability and its confidence interval. But what do you mean by your second way? I mean what do you mean by the sentence *if you know a  initio what the distribution of d's go into your quadratic/cubic equations*, I should say that 62271000s *aQuardratic*s and **aCubic*s are constant across the whole image. And for each pixel the *62271x1 vector of b*s in quadratic equation and *62271x1 vectors of b and c*s in cubic equation is the same. I mean the vector (cont.)

Comment: is the same for a pixel. Meaning that the values will differ in each iteration and they are different for different pixels. And c in the quadratic equation is a 62271x1 vector of constant values. And d in the quadratic equation is a 62271x1 vector of constant values. I mean yes we have prior knowledge about the coefficients just based on values for each pixel. I'll try to add a .mat file of the variables *QuadraticCoefficients* and **CubicCoefficient** an hour later to let you see what I mean. And yes for a given 25x40 matrix I can draw the graph of coefficients and so guess their distribution

Comment: @Wiley probably I'm going to cite thjs question inmy thesis and so I really love that this question had an answer. Would you rather add an answer based on your second way or introduce me some resour esabout tha random matrix theory tofind theanswer by my self andadd it?

Comment: I am glad that you found the comments helpful, but I don't think I understand well enough what you are asking for to add any answer (and this could be the reason why your question hasn't got enough attention).  Maybe we can start with a concrete example, e.g., your 2d case: do I understand it correctly that you want the eigenvalues of $[[0,-d_3],~[1,-d_2]]$, i.e., the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2+d_2\lambda+d_3=0$?.  Across your whole image, do you have an idea of what the distributions of $d_2$ and $d_3$ are? (cont.)

Comment: In the setup above, I am not sure how you have reached to the conclusion that the probability of the quadratic equation having two negative roots is $1/4$.  It could be the case that $d_3$ is always negative to make sure that you have two real roots, but then you wind up 100% probability of having one positive root and one negative root.  It would be helpful if you could clarify this in your question.